# MySQL trigger if-else insert update

Tags: mysql, sql, if-statement, database-trigger

I'm trying to make this code work but to no avail..

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE
    TRIGGER `update_tbl1` AFTER UPDATE 
    ON `tbl1` 
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

        IF (SELECT count(*) FROM tbl1 WHERE stn=NEW.stn) = 1
        THEN
        UPDATE tbl2 SET date_posted=NEW.date_posted WHERE stn=NEW.stn;
        ELSE
        INSERT INTO tbl2 (stn) VALUES (NEW.stn);
        END IF

    END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

I have two tables, and I want a trigger that will update tbl2 if the tbl1 is updated, only if the data already exists on the tbl2, otherwise, insert it. My code seems feasible and the error seems to be syntax-related but I can't find where.

EDIT:

Here is the error:

```
 #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INTO tbl2 (stn) VALUES (NEW.stn); END IF END' at line 10
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

About syntax error, I think it's just what you forgot semicolon `;` after `END IF`, try following:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE
    TRIGGER `update_tbl1` AFTER UPDATE 
    ON `tbl1` 
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

        IF (SELECT count(*) FROM tbl1 WHERE stn=NEW.stn) = 1
        THEN
        UPDATE tbl2 SET date_posted=NEW.date_posted WHERE stn=NEW.stn;
        ELSE
        INSERT INTO tbl2 (stn) VALUES (NEW.stn);
        END IF;

    END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: I am so embarrassed, but thank you for your eagle eyes! :)

Comment: Thanks @Blank for this tip, it just helped me with a trigger I was struggling with. You and Stackoverflow saved the day :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the syntax error is, but the logic you want is:

```
INSERT INTO tbl2 (stn)
    VALUES (NEW.stn)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE SET date_posted = NEW.date_posted;
```

For this to work, you need a unique index on `tbl2(stn)`:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX unq_tbl2_stn ON tbl2(stn);
```

Note:  This doesn't fix your particular syntax error.  This addresses a logical error in the code.